# How to Modify Elements from JQuery Click Event

Tags: jquery, html

I have a link like this:

```
 <a class="search_res_click" target="_blank" href="#">
 <div>
  // lot of stuff here
 </div>

 </a>
```

And I attached an event to all such links via following:

```
$(".search_res_click").click(function(e) {
    $(".search_res_click").children().css("opacity", "1");
    $(e).css("opacity", "0.5");
    console.log($(e));
});
```

The function of the event handler is to change the opacity of the clicked link. But when I am clicking on the link it is not changing the opacity.

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: `e` is an event, not the element itself. Use `$(this)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$(this).css("opacity", "0.5");
```

or

```
$(e.currentTarget).css("opacity", "0.5");
```

because `e` is object not element